# Connect to an SQL server hosted on a remote machine with a Public STATIC IP, and also modify and add stuff there

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm a beginner at VB.net and I wanted to try out some stuff on VB.net to get acquainted with it., hope you don't mind.

So, to connect to a Database hosted on my VPS, I tried this out

```
Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Data Source=censored;Initial Catalog=censored;User ID=mydbuser;Password=mydbpass"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Opened. Queries can be successfully performed now.")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Cannot open, please check the information.")
    End Try
```

It gave me an error saying that it cannot open as it definitely caught an exception.

I also wanted to know how I can edit and add values in the tables in the SQL Server that I make a connection to.

Thanks in advance, best regards..

B-ME

Comment: Catching an exception and say _'ops there is an error'_ is not a good practice. If you want you could print out the Exception.Message property to let us know what really happens that cause the exception. In real code, just log the exception data and exit as soon as possible..

Comment: Now that you built up all the suspense: What does the exception message say?

Comment: I did put in all the correct information for the SQL, as I use from PHPmyadmin(to connect to it) it gives me an error saying it cannot open even though I imported system and system.data.sqlconnection and so on
(I might be acting dumb and I am sorry for that in advance)

Comment: Have you tried pinging it from your machine that you are running the code on?

Comment: Yes I have, it does not respond really since its supposed to be like that(to prevent attacks on it, as the host says) but I can fully connect to it using Navicat(a GUI based application to access SQL) using the default SQL port. @JustinHui

Comment: Have you included the port in the connection string?

Comment: @JustinHui - Thought that didn't make a difference, so I just tried it like a minute ago. Gives me the same error of not being able to open a connection.

Comment: Is it a MS SQL server or something else?  If it's MYSQL or something other than MS SQL Server you may have to use special connectors

Comment: Otherwise have you tried using the IP address as described here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/

Comment: @JustinHui - Its a MySQL server. I shall try those but can you help me and tell me what exactly is "library"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the .NET driver for MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Then you should be able to use it as described here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html

Right click on your project and make sure there is a reference to the MySQL Connector, if not add it.

Put this at the top:

```
Imports System.Data    
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Then try something like:

```
 Dim connectionString As String
 Dim cnn As MySqlConnection
 connectionString = "server=censored;user=mydbuser;database=censored;port=3306;password=mydbpass;"
 cnn = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
 Try
     cnn.Open()
     MsgBox("Opened. Queries can be successfully performed now.")
     cnn.Close()
  Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
```

Comment: Really appreciate that help but I am not acquainted with that language, I'm using VB.net and I think I already do have that(I BELIEVE) @JustinHui

Comment: I've added some example code, see if that helps you